# How to Convert simple function to grab from Web Service instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice-client

I have this function in a .cs file, with the following code that just sets a website url, like so:

```
public string GetWebsite()
{
    Url theUrl = _Urls.Find(u => u.UrlType == UrlType.Main);

    if (theUrl != null)
    {
        return theUrl.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }        
}
```

theUrl is defined within another .cs file as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MMG.CMS
{
    [DataContract] [Serializable] public class Url
    {
        #region Data Declarations
        [DataMember(Name = "Name",    IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = true)] private string  _Name    = "";
        [DataMember(Name = "Value",   IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = true)] private string  _Value   = "";
        [DataMember(Name = "UrlType", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = true)] private UrlType _UrlType = UrlType.None;
        private object       _Tag    = null;
        private List<string> _Errors = new List<string>();
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Url()
        {

        }
        public Url(string aName, string aValue, UrlType aType)
        {
            _Name = aName;
            _Value = aValue;
            _UrlType = aType;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public bool Validate()
        {
            bool _IsValidated = true;

            if (_Value.Trim() == "") { _Errors.Add("Please Enter a Url!"); _IsValidated = false; }
            if (_UrlType == UrlType.None) { _Errors.Add("Please Enter a Type!"); _IsValidated = false; }

            return _IsValidated;
        }
        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return (_Name.Trim() == "") &&
                   (_Value.Trim() == "") &&
                   (_UrlType == UrlType.None);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        public string       Name    
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
        public string       Value   
        {
            get
            {
                return _Value.ToLower().StartsWith("www") ? "http://" + _Value : _Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _Value = value;
            }
        }
        public UrlType      UrlType 
        {
            get
            {
                return _UrlType;
            }
            set
            {
                _UrlType = value;
            }
        }
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
        public object       Tag     
        {
            get
            {
                return _Tag;
            }
            set
            {
                _Tag = value;
            }
        }
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
        public List<string> Errors  
        {
            get
            {
                return _Errors;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I would like to convert it to grab the website from a Web Service instead, something like this:

```
public string GetWebsite()
{
    ServiceMemberIDSS.MembersSoapClient client = new ServiceMemberIDSS.MembersSoapClient();
    ServiceMemberIDSS.Member[] theMembers = client.GetMemberList(IDSSCredentials(), true, true, true, true, false);

    int IDSS_ID = 0;

    // Lookup the IDSS Member ID based on their Email for now.
    foreach(Member theMember in theMembers)
    {
        if (theMember.MemberAccount.Email.ToString() == GetEmailAddress().ToString())
        {
            IDSS_ID = theMember.MemberID;
            break;
        }
    }

    ServiceMemberIDSS.Member thisMember = client.GetMember(IDSSCredentials(), IDSS_ID, true, true, true, true, false);


    return thisMember.MemberAccount.Website.ToString();
}
```

Currently, I have to use GetMemberList to get all members, and than use GetEmailAddress to match only the member with that email address in order to get the correct Member ID for that member.

GetEmailAddress looks like this:

```
public string GetEmailAddress()
{
    EmailAddress theEmail = _EmailAddresses.Find(u => u.EmailAddressType == EmailAddressType.Main);

    if (theEmail != null)
    {
        return theEmail.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Am I doing this in the right file?  When I make that change to `GetWebsite()` I get blank areas returned for these sections instead of the Member Information, including the website url.  I know the Web Service returns something, but it just isn't showing anything, and all other areas of that user control are now blank as well.

Should I be doing this edit elsewhere?  What could be causing the control to return blank areas for this?  Do I have to set `_Urls` somehow?

Comment: This question totally depends on what your classes are designed to do and how they function, how your data services contracts are meant to operate, etc. It's not answerable as is.

Comment: Ok, how can I help to make this answerable?